# WPF Windows Presentation Foundation Animation using MultiTrigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, multitrigger

I am trying to get the hang of how to do animations using WPF XAML. I'm struggeling to get my animation to trigger based on the right conditions and now I need some help.

Just for laughs I want to make a page with a button that will dodge any attempt to be pressed by moving to a different place on the canvas. Here is an illustration of my desired animations:
[image]

I want to solve the problem simply using XAML (and no code-behind), but I am open to a solution which uses code if the code is accompanied with an explanation of why this can not be solved simply by declaring the appropriate XAML.

This is what I have so far:

```
 <Page x:Class="myApp.SecondPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  xmlns:c="clr-namespace:myApp"
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="500"
Title="SecondPage" Height="300" Width="500">
<Page.Resources>        
    <PathGeometry x:Key="AnimationPath" Figures="M 0,0 C -130,-100 -130,-60 -130,-0"/>
    <Style x:Key="secondButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="Button"></Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger >
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition  Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"></Condition>
 <!--Doesn't work --><Condition Property="TranslateTransform.X" Value="0"></Condition>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath x:Name="XAnim"
                                   FillBehavior="HoldEnd"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.X"
                                   PathGeometry="{StaticResource AnimationPath}"
                                   Source="X" 
                                   Duration="0:0:.2"  
                                   />
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath x:Name="YAnim"
                                   FillBehavior="HoldEnd"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Y"                                       
                                   PathGeometry="{StaticResource AnimationPath}"
                                   Source="Y" 
                                   Duration="0:0:.2"  
                                  />                             
                        </Storyboard>

                    </BeginStoryboard>

                </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

    <Grid>
    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="MyCanvas" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsManipulationEnabled="True">
      <Button  Style="{StaticResource secondButton}" Canvas.Left="150" Canvas.Top="240" Height="48" x:Name="theButton" Width="115" FontSize="18" ForceCursor="False">
            <Button.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="AnimatedTranslateTransform"/>
            </Button.RenderTransform>
        </Button>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

In my second multitrigger condition I am trying to check where the button is (in order to start the right storyboard). I simply cannot seem to figure out which property and value to use in the condition to evaluate whether the button is on the *left* or *right* hand side. The `TranslateTransform.X` property doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to work with `MultiDataTrigger` here to get through the Transform:

```
<Style x:Key="secondButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <!-- ... -->
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}"
                        Value="True" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=RenderTransform.X}"
                        Value="0"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <!-- ... -->
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

(*In a normal MultiTrigger you can only access immediate properties, `Property="TranslateTransform.X"` is not only wrong since it should be `Property="RenderTransform.X"` but it further would be evaluated as an attached property which does not exist*)

Since you named the Transform you could also use a binding using `ElementName` instead of `RelativeSource` in the second condition.

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=AnimatedTranslateTransform, Path=X}"
           Value="0"/>
```

Comment: +1 Thanks! This looks like a good answer. Sadly, I don't have the opportunity to verify (and accept) it until monday. I *did* briefly consider the MultiDataTrigger, but thought it was primarily for working with *data* (from reading the documentation).

Comment: Just consider the Transform's state to be data then :), i don't think you need to worry about it that much.

Comment: I am still quite inexperienced with WPF and XAML, and the concept that something can define a binding using `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}` was new to me. Right now it looks like the missing piece in my puzzle.

Comment: You might want to read [this article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) then. (And/or some of the other [articles on WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx) which are all quite good)